# Macbook Pro running Mojave dropping bluetooth devices

Tags: keyboard, mojave, bluetooth, mouse

I'm having a strange bluetooth problem: my mid 2015 MB Pro connects to my bluetooth magic mouse and keyboard fine. After a few minutes of use, both disconnect (I get the "connection lost" icon for both mouse and keyboard). About 10 seconds later, both reconnect. This entire cycle happens every few minutes. I've looked all over for help but haven't found the same problem. Could this be interference? I've tried all the usual bluetooth debugging but can't work out what's happening. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes resetting the SMC can help How to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac - Apple Support -> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295